# sed: just trying to remove a substring

Tags: linux, shell, sed

I have a file with this content:

```
foo:&nbsp;bar1
foo:&nbsp;bar2
foo:&nbsp;bar3
foo:&nbsp;bar4
foo:&nbsp;bar5
```

I want to remove the chains "foo: " so the file remains:

```
bar1
bar2
bar3
...
```

I'm trying it with:

```
$ sed 's/foo:&nbsp;/' file.txt
```

but it says:

> sed: -e expression #1, char 15: unterminated `s' command

Any help?

Javi

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You need to:

```
$ sed -r 's/^foo:&nbsp;//' file.txt
```

Comment: If the file only has the above content, would not `sed 's/.*;//' file.txt` be suffice?

Comment: @poton Yes, that would do just as well. IMHO, though, it's better to be more specific. You never know, right?

Comment: The `-r` isn't necessary in this case and it's not available in some versions of `sed`.

Answer (score 11):

**Your `file`**

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat file
foo:&nbsp;bar1
foo:&nbsp;bar2
foo:&nbsp;bar3
foo:&nbsp;bar4
foo:&nbsp;bar5
```

**Using `awk`:**

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] awk -F";" '{print $NF}' file
bar1
bar2
bar3
bar4
bar5
```

**Using `sed`**

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] sed 's/.*;//' file
bar1
bar2
bar3
bar4
bar5
```

**Using `cut`**

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cut -d";" -f2 file
bar1
bar2
bar3
bar4
bar5
```

Answer (score 3):

For this simple task you can use `cut`:

```
 cut -b 11- INPUTFILE
```

HTH

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F';' '{print $2}' file
```

or

```
grep -Po '(?<=&nbsp;).*$' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Practical example using sed to strip off a substring  and then copy to paste buffer (linux)
Scanning an Autohotkey config file on linux (sadly no autohotkey for linux) . '::' is used as a delimiter in AHK

```
grep -Eie "xxx::" AutoHotkey.ahk | sed 's/^.*:://' | xclip
```

Answer (score 0):

OP is asking to change the **FILE**.

So, if you want to change the **FILE**, use `-i`:

```
sed -i 's/^foo:&nbsp;//' file.txt
```